# Alternative to Dynamic Data in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, breeze, dynamic-data, scaffolding

Years ago Microsoft present Dynamic Data as a new generation scaffolding engine to make the fastest way to manage your data without mostly any code writing.

After some years without any news and without support for Entity Framework 6.x Dynamic Data is 
closed.
Yes they make MvcScaffolding which is quite easy to use as a nice sample but it's not dynamic it let update code every you change your database (maybe I don't have some skills and this is easy or can be automatic).
So have anybody found something new to manage EF models? Maybe this is something written with JavaScript (with breeze and OData that will looks interesting)?
So I would be glad to hear about anything interesting to give up old Dynamic Data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2014-01-30: [Dynamic Data is back!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/30/announcing-preview-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx)

2014-02-28: [Dynamic Data is out of alpha, and a release version is available.](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.EFProvider/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks to update correct answer. I forgot to do it myself

Comment: Any resources for implementing this in .NET MVC5?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio LightSwitch may be an option, however I don't know if it will still be about in a few years time.

Oneday someone will come up with a web solution that works as well as MS-Access for simple data.

Answer (score 1):

I am using CamoteQ scaffolding tool.

https://camoteq.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

How dynamic do you want to go? Using T4 templates in your solution and re-running these will re-scaffold your templates which essentially makes them dynamic.

Comment: Well, in fact in one step behind cause I need to update scaffolding project every my model change but maybe it will totally be a profit cause of better extensibility comparing to Dynamic Data. I'll play with updating, thanks.

Comment: Ok, Asp.Net Mvc Scaffolding it's good but even this article http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview doesn't show how to rerun T4 transformation. Can you help with it?

Answer (score 0):

Intead of `Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.EFProvider` you can use AJAX and ASP.NET MVC without needing to download a separate NuGet package other than I think EntityFramework:

First create an employee table in a database with EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Email, Phone and Experience.

Then create an ASP.NET Web Application, choosing MVC, in Visual Studio.  Now add this to your HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities ();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.EmployeeInfos.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult EmployeeInfo(int id)
    {
        List<EmployeeInfo> EmpInfo = db.EmployeeInfos.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == id).ToList();
        return View(EmpInfo);
    }
}
```

Next in your HomeController View open Index.cshml, and put in this code:

```
@model IEnumerable<DynamicallyLoadingContant.Models.EmployeeInfo>
           <br /><br />
<div class="container">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">-----Employee List-----</h3><br />
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:20%">ID</th>
            <th style="width:80%">Name</th>
        </tr>
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <tr>
               <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
               <td><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" id="@item.EmployeeId">@item.EmployeeName</a></td>
           </tr>
       }
    </table>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            title: setData,
            html: true,
            placement:'right'

        });
        function setData(id) {
            var set_data = '';
            var element = $(this);
            var id = element.attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/EmployeeInfo?id" + id,
                method: "post",
                async: false,
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    set_data = data;
                }

            });
            return set_data;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Next add another EmployeeInfo.cshtml view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DynamicallyLoadingContant.Models.EmployeeInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeInfo";
}
<div class="container">
    <h4 style=" text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #808080">EmployeeInfo</h4>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <p><label>Name : </label> @item.EmployeeName</p>
        <p><label>Email : </label> @item.Email</p>
        <p><label>Phone : </label> @item.Phone</p>
        <p><label>Experience : </label> @item.Experience</p>
    }
</div>
```

For more details, please see http://abctutorial.com/Post/29/dynamically-loading-content-with-jquery-ajax-%7C-aspnet-mvc